# Spare PC with XP to be used as Torrent Downloader and local Web Server HOWTO?

Tags: windows-xp, networking, webserver

Hi I'm a bit in a pickle in trying to setup my old laptop using Windows XP to be able to serve as two devices in one, I want to make it a downloader for torrents and a local web server as well and how to do this?

I have a wireless NIC and LAN, and I have two internet connections and i would like to be able to download torrent only on LAN and be a webserver on the Wireless, also the webserver can be accessed through the internet. The reason for trying to separate the connection is I can't have torrent downloads using all my bandwidth as my web pages cant be access as it times out or too slow.

I have two broadband connections, is this even possible or would i need a different OS or program that I can download? please

Answer (score 0):

For a start, Windows XP is not a good OS to act as a server.

If you still want to go ahead -

If you use IIS, you will be limited to 10 concurrent connections, so I would recommend looking at Apache or an alternate server.

Next, I am guessing you have two routers. What you need to do is connect both interfaces to their network, so ethernet to one.

I would suggest using the ethernet network as the main/torrent one as this will be most demanding. At the router/firewall, set it up normally so that there is an open port and forwarded to the machine. Also, if your torrent client supports it, map it to only this interface/address.

Next, set the wireless one up, but set up the network address manually and make sure it is on a separate network range. Forward port 80 from the wireless router to your machine and on your webserver, make sure it is only set to listen to that IP address.

This is quite complicated, if you don't understand or want more help, please give the IP/subnet and any other relevant details of your network and I will try to tell you the settings needed.